# jQuery stop append removing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am copying a div into another div using append. However it removes the original. I tried to use clone but it seems to only work with appendTo. But appendTo breaks my layout so I have to use append with works fine.

I am wrong that clone will not work with .append and is there another way to stop the div removing?

Thanks

```
              $('.compareWrapper').append(htmlStr)
```

Comment: Clone does work with append.  Could you show us the code that didn't work?

Comment: Show some relevant html. AFAIK, append should never remove any html

Comment: How did you try to use clone and appendTo? Are you wanting to add the div into another div or just what is in that div? Append does move HTML according to the docs - "As shown in the discussion for .append(), normally when an element is inserted somewhere in the DOM, it is moved from its old location."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo.appendTo(bar)`
Take `foo` and append it to `bar`.

`foo.append(bar)`
Take `bar` and append it to `foo`

Syntactically they're different. You have to think of what's the target object and what's the destination object. So, having said that you can move ahead in one of two ways:

```
var $clone = $('target').clone();
$clone.appendTo('wrapper');
$('wrapper').append($clone);
```

[Both do the same thing.](http://jsfiddle.net/yMXyG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The following does not work?

```
$('.compareWrapper').append($(htmlStr).clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason for `.clone()` not working with `.append()`. The code should be:

```
$('.compareWrapper').append($(htmlStr).clone());
```

Is that what you tried? From the name of your variable, I'm assuming `htmlStr` is a string, not a jQuery object.

Comment: I am useing var htmlStr = $(this).parents(".listingContainer").first(); I tried to put in an alert to view the string but it had the word object.